Tidycmprsk - issue with level labels
I am really enjoying the package tidycmprsk.
However, I stepped across a problem that cannot be solve by ordering etc: It is not possible to reorder the appearance of the curves if you rename them.
In my case, I had a variable coded 1,2,3 and needed to rename it to have the correct labels in the risk table.
However, after re-naming, they appear in alphabetical order, and this order cannot be changed regardless of what you try.
Here is an example code:
library(tidycmprsk)

trial <- trial
label_levels <- c("Beta", "Alpha")

trial$trt <- factor(trial$trt,
                    levels = c("Drug A", "Drug B"),
                    labels = label_levels)

tidycmprsk::cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc(outcome = "death from cancer") +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable() +
  scale_ggsurvfit()

Can anybody help me out?
I either want to overwrite level labels in the risk table (add_risktable()), or change the label levels in the dataframe directly.
In my case, I had a variable coded 1,2,3 and needed to rename it to have the correct labels in the risk table.
However, after re-naming, they appear in alphabetical order, and this order cannot be changed regardless of what you try.

I have the same problem where the order of the risk table is alphabetical instead of following the factor levels. Have you been able to solve this?

Dear Saskia, unfortunately this seems to be a problem/bug of the package.
However, what I did, is leaving the factor levels as 1,2,3 (then it is ordered accordingly), and then overwriting it with

add_risktable(theme = list(scale_y_discrete(label = c('XXX', 'XXX','XXX'))

for the risk table legend, and

scale_color_manual() for the figure lgend.

